# HAVING Clause in SQL Server is Ignored

Tags: sql-server

I have a PURCHASES table that has a unique ID of PURCHASE_ID.  I want to break down how many distinct customers purchases they had per year that had at least 2 unique purchases.  This is the query that I wrote:

```
SELECT 
  YEAR(PURCHASE_TIME) PURCHASE_YEAR,
  COUNT(DISTINCT CUSTOMER_ID) TOTAL_CUSTOMERS
FROM PURCHASES
GROUP BY YEAR(PURCHASE_TIME)
HAVING COUNT(PURCHASE_ID) > 1
```

However, this query is giving me the total distinct patients per year of purchase no matter how many purchases they had.  Meaning, that I am getting customers that had only 1 purchase for the year AND those that had more than one.  It is as if the HAVING clause is being ignored.
It doesn’t change anything if I use a `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT PURCHASE_ID) > 1` either.  Even though I shouldn’t technically need that since the PURCHASE_ID is already unique and is a primary key.

This works though.

```
SELECT 
  PURCHASE_YEAR,
  COUNT(DISTINCT CUSTOMER_ID) TOTAL_CUSTOMERS
FROM
(
  SELECT 
    YEAR(PURCHASE_TIME) PURCHASE_YEAR, 
    CUSTOMER_ID
  FROM PURCHASES
  GROUP BY YEAR(PURCHASE_TIME),CUSTOMER_ID
  HAVING COUNT(PURCHASE_ID) > 1
) VW
GROUP BY PURCHASE_YEAR
```

Comment: You aren't grouping by `CUSTOMER_ID` in your first query so how do you expect it to know that's what you want?

Comment: The way I see it is that the HAVING clause should only be giving me records though for those having more than one purchase.  Then I am doing a distinct count of those customers by year.

Comment: That may be the way you see it but it ain't what you have coded! You are grouping by year so it will return those years with at least one purchase.

Comment: Ok.  So what effect is the HAVING COUNT(PURCHASE_ID) > 1 having on that query?  I see the first query giving me a distinct count of customers per calendar year since that is the only grouping.  The HAVING clause then is evaluated second right?  So this is then saying out of those, only give those records from that grouping by year with a count of PURCHASE_ID > 1.

Comment: Your first query divides the data up into one group for each year then for each group (i.e. year) counts the number of `purchase_Id`s in that year. If any of the years has `<=1` then it will be excluded.

Comment: Ok, I definitely agree up until the part that you say it counts the number of PURCHASE_IDs in that year because I am using a  COUNT(DISTINCT CUSTOMER_ID) TOTAL_CUSTOMERS in the SELECT statement.

Comment: Yes and that returns the number of distinct customer_ids per group (i.e. per year) and returns it. But it doesn't affect what is happening in the `having` clause.

Comment: Ok, I think I have it now.  Having is restricting to PURCHASE_ID counts per year since that is the grouping, but since it is only grouped by year it will give only years where there are more than one purchase ID.  If I group by year and customer ID then it is giving me the grouping per year, per customer where there is more than one purchase per customer per year.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
    SELECT PURCHASE_YEAR,
    COUNT(1) AS CNT
    FROM 
        (SELECT YEAR(PURCHASE_TIME) PURCHASE_YEAR,
        CUSTOMER_ID
        FROM PURCHASES 
        GROUP BY YEAR(PURCHASE_TIME), 
                 CUSTOMER_ID
        HAVING COUNT(1) > 1) AS CNT
    GROUP BY PURCHASE_YEAR
    ORDER BY PURCHASE_YEAR
```

Comment: Placing your having clause in a subquery like this will ensure that out query only sees the records that meet the requirements.  If this is 2005 or later I think a CTE would be more readable, but this tecnique should work quote well.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
SELECT 
  YEAR(PURCHASE_TIME) PURCHASE_YEAR,
  COUNT(CUSTOMER_ID) TOTAL_CUSTOMERS
FROM PURCHASES
GROUP BY YEAR(PURCHASE_TIME), CUSTOMER_ID
HAVING COUNT(PURCHASE_ID) > 1
```

Comment: That will bring back 1 row per customer b/c of the GROUP BY

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `DISTINCT` to your filter:

```
SELECT 
  YEAR(PURCHASE_TIME) PURCHASE_YEAR,
  COUNT(DISTINCT CUSTOMER_ID) TOTAL_CUSTOMERS
FROM PURCHASES
GROUP BY YEAR(PURCHASE_TIME)
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT PURCHASE_ID) > 1
```

Comment: This is one that I tried as well, but I still get those customers that have only one purchase.

Comment: @bjsql are you sure you added the `DISTINCT` to the `HAVING` clause? `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT PURCHASE_ID) > 1`  I worked fine for me.